# Why is the label not getting displayed in this SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT (SAMPLE(?sport) AS ?sport) ?sportLabel (SAMPLE(?uses) AS ?uses) (SAMPLE(?usesLabel) AS ?usesLabel)
WHERE 
{
  # instance of sport
  ?sport wdt:P31 wd:Q31629.
  FILTER (!isBlank(?uses))
  OPTIONAL { ?sport wdt:P2283 ?uses } .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} 
GROUP BY ?sportLabel
```

Not able to get the label of uses. ?usesLabel returns blank strings but ?uses returns correct ids

Comment: the magic label service works after the aggregate function only

Comment: `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?sportLabel ?usesLabel {
{SELECT ?sport (SAMPLE(?uses) AS ?uses)  
WHERE 
{
  # instance of sport
  ?sport wdt:P31 wd:Q31629.
  FILTER (!isBlank(?uses))
  OPTIONAL { ?sport wdt:P2283 ?uses } .
  
}   
GROUP BY ?sport}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }}`

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two options.

(Note: I replaced `(SAMPLE(?sport) AS ?sport)` with `?sport`, as you presumably want to list all sport items.)

#### Using a subquery

You could use a subquery to aggregate everything, and the outer query to display the labels:

```
SELECT ?sport ?sportLabel ?usesSample ?usesSampleLabel
WHERE {
  
  {
    SELECT ?sport (SAMPLE(?uses) AS ?usesSample)
    WHERE {

      # instance of sport
      ?sport wdt:P31 wd:Q31629 .

      FILTER (!isBlank(?uses)) .
      OPTIONAL { ?sport wdt:P2283 ?uses . } 

    } GROUP BY ?sport
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }

}
```

#### Using Wikidata’s label service

You could keep your current query, and add the labels you need to the `SERVICE`:

```
SELECT ?sport ?sportLabel (SAMPLE(?usesLabel) AS ?usesSampleLabel)
WHERE 
{

  # instance of sport
  ?sport wdt:P31 wd:Q31629 .
  
  FILTER (!isBlank(?uses)) .
  OPTIONAL { ?sport wdt:P2283 ?uses . }
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    ?sport rdfs:label ?sportLabel .
    ?uses rdfs:label ?usesLabel .
  }
  
} 
GROUP BY ?sport ?sportLabel
```