# How can I group multiple results into one cell with SPARQL in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to pull (lots of) data for one of my projects.
Specifically trying to get some data on biblical figures.
However, I've noticed that when there are mutiple results per column, I get the results in a new raw. Meaning, there is no option to put multiple results in one row , with a seperator for example.

For example, since some biblical figures have more than one sibling, I get the results in mutpile rows:

[Here's an example for a query with siblings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQzeG.png)

I tried to group by but [got an error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaLEW.png)

select ?person ?personLabel ?siblingLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?personLabel) AS ?personLabels)
where {
?person wdt:P31 wd:Q20643955.
?person wdt:P3373 ?sibling.
SERVICE wikibase:label {
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
}
}
GROUP BY ?person
ORDER BY ?personLabel

Comment: `group by` + `group_concat` as aggregate function is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all siblings in a cell, you have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on `?siblingLabel`, not `?personLabel`. To omit duplicate labels, you can add `DISTINCT` to it. To use a delimiter (e.g., a semicolon), you can add `SEPARATOR` to it.

```
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?siblingLabel; SEPARATOR="; ") AS ?siblingLabels)
```

To the `GROUP BY` you have to add all other variables.

As you are getting the labels with Wikidata’s label service, [one more step is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74375458/19579546): You either have to use a sub-query, or you have to list the labels you need in the `SERVICE`.

Using the latter, your query could be:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?siblingLabel; SEPARATOR="; ") AS ?siblingLabels)
WHERE {

  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q20643955 ;
          wdt:P3373 ?sibling . 
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . 
    ?sibling rdfs:label ?siblingLabel .
    ?person rdfs:label ?personLabel .
  }

} 
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel
ORDER BY ?personLabel
```