# SPARQL query to get an object that is shared (connected to) by two subjects

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I have the following graph

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:JupiterAtmsphere     :isComposedOf      :Nitrogen.
:JupiterAtmsphere     :isComposedOf      :Helium.
:EarthAtmosphere      :isComposedOf      :Nitrogen.

:comet_1              :hasDiscoverer     :JohnSmith.
:comet_5              :hasDiscoverer     :JohnSmith.
:comet_3              :hasDiscoverer     :JaneLee.
```

I want to return all predicates and objects that are shared by a number of subjects. The query is trying to answer the following question: Which 'subjects' share 'object' in common?. I'd like the query to return :Nitrogen as an object that is shared by both :JupiterAtmspher and :EarthAtmspher, and :JohnSmith as an object that is shared by :comet_1 and :comet_5
However, the challenge is that I want the query to be generic (without prior knowledge of the subjects, predicates or objects of the graph). In other words, I'm desinging a query that is generic and can be applied to different ontologies regardless of their vocabulary.

I tried the following query which did not yeild the desired result:

```
SELECT ?class1 ?class2 ?p1   ?o
WHERE {
  ?class1       ?p1         ?o.
  ?class2       ?p2         ?o.
FILTER (?p1 = ?p2)
```

Comment: `SELECT ?class1 ?class2 ?p1   ?o
WHERE {
  ?class1       ?p1         ?o.
  ?class2       ?p1         ?o.
FILTER (?class1 != ?class2)` would return pairs of subject sharing same predicate and object in RDF triples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to state that the subjects need to be different. You can do this with the `!=` operator in a `FILTER`:

```
SELECT ?s1 ?s2 ?p1 ?o
WHERE {

  ?s1 ?p1 ?o .

  ?s2 ?p2 ?o .

  FILTER (?s1 != ?s2) .

} ORDER BY ?o ?p1
```

If the predicates need to be the same, replace `?p1` and `?p2` with `?p`.

(Note: This query finds objects that are shared by ***at least*** two subjects.)

With `GROUP_CONCAT`, you could get one result solution per object+predicate (e.g., with a comma-separated list of subjects).

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. However, can you please elaborate on how to use the GROUP_CONCAT in this case?

Comment: @SamahK: Maybe [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726755/19579546) helps (you can ignore the `SERVICE` part).  If you can’t get it to work, I would suggest to create another question, showing what you’ve tried.